# What if anything was the correspondence between mishmarim of kohanim and cities?

Tags: geography, kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash, city-of-refuge

There were twenty-four watches (*mishmarim*) of *kohanim*. Each worked for a week, from *Shabas* to *Shabas*, and then the cycle repeated itself. ([*Rambam*, *K'le Hamikdash* 4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%95_%D7%93).)

[There were forty-eight cities in which *shevet Levi* lived.](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%97_%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9_%D7%97)

Was there only one city per watch of *kohanim*, or did a watch live in more than one city?

Was there only one watch per city, or did a city house more than one watch?

(Perhaps there was no correspondence at all between watches and cities. I have no reason to think there was one, except that travel to and from Jerusalem might be easier en masse and that twenty-four is half of forty-eight.)

Comment: Do we know Kohanim lived in the Levite cities, and not their own?

Comment: At least Second Temple watches all lived in separate cities, per this Kinnah http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19663&st=&pgnum=24&hilite=

Comment: @DoubleAA I was assuming the cities were for _kohanim_ also. Any correction of a misapprehension would be appreciated, and may serve as an answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA How do you see that from that _kina_?

Comment: Well in it we have a listing of 24 cities, so they must have lived independent of each other.

Comment: @DoubleAA How do you know those are cities, not merely names of watches?

Comment: Because among them is Beit Lechem, Kefar Uziel, Tzefat, Tzippori, Ma'on and Nazareth. Besides, what else would you name them after?

Comment: @DoubleAA, if each watch came from a specific city, then, yes, doubtless it came from the city it was named after. But if not, then they may have been named after cities anyway, much as (_l'havdil_) color-war teams in summer camp may be named "_Chevron_" and "_Tz'fas_".